# How can i get Object.assign() to work in the browser when using 6to5?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using the 6to5 transpiler. When I try to use Object.assign() in my code, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object.assign is not a function`. How can I enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest release, where *6to5 has been renamed to Babel*, you no longer need to do this. You can either configure it to use a polyfill or load the runtime. This is how I have set it up in gulp:

```
browserify({debug : true})
.transform(

    // We want to convert JSX to normal javascript
    babelify.configure({

        // load the runtime to be able to use Object.assign
        optional: ["runtime"]
    })
);
```

You configuration should be pretty similar, no matter what tool you use. Using the package standalone would look like this:

```
require("babel").transform("code", { optional: ["runtime"] });
```

You can look at the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/) for `runtime`. Remember to update to the latest version of babel, though! It updates very frequently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the `browser-polyfill.js` file:

> Available from the `browser-polyfill.js` file within the 6to5 directory of an npm release. This needs to be included **before** all your compiled 6to5 code. You can either prepend it to your compiled code or include it in a `<script>` before it.
>
> **NOTE**: Do not `require` this via browserify etc, use `6to5/polyfill`.

http://6to5.org/docs/usage/polyfill/